# How to format Session datetime value in aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, session

How to format Session datetime value in `aspx` itself to get the date part only.

---

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Session["start_date_lect"]%>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your code like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",Session["start_date_lect"])%>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks but I get a compilation error `'string' does not contain a definition for 'format'`